# How can I emit Socket.io events from a router file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am working on a socket.io project in which I need to emit an event when the `/` page is requested. But all my routings are in a separate file `router/index.js`. Now, I want to emit a socket event on the page request from the router file.

I can't find a way to sort this out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your socket object in separate file and export it.
//let io.js

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
module.export.io = io;
```

now in route/index.js;

```
var io = require('io.js')
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
  io.sockets.emit('home.accessed');
})
```

simlarly if socket code was in server.js

require it from io.js likewise.